# faster than Stackwalk

Tags: c++, windows, callstack

Does anybody know of a better/ faster way to get the call stack than "StackWalk"?
I also think that stackwalk can also be slower on methods with a lot of variables...
(I wonder what commercial profilers do?)
I'm using C++ on windows. :)
thanks :)

Comment: Valgrind? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: hmmm... isn't valgrind only for unix?

Comment: and valgrind is instrumenting, I'm looking for a better way to sample the stack...

Comment: Why isn't StackWalk fast enough for you? What do you need it for?

Comment: I'm trying to write my own little profiler and i'm trying to make it as fast as i can :)

Comment: I ran into this same issue.  I wrote a leak-tracking smart pointer which relied on `StackWalk` but it's *very* slow.  How do apps like Process Monitor do it (since PM logs the stack for every single file/registry access incredibly quickly)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's faster, and it won't show you any symbols, and I'm sure you can do better than that, but this is some code I wrote a while back when I needed this info (only works for Windows):

```
struct CallStackItem
{
    void* pc;
    CallStackItem* next;

    CallStackItem()
    {
        pc = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

typedef void* CallStackHandle;

CallStackHandle CreateCurrentCallStack(int nLevels)
{
    void** ppCurrent = NULL;

    // Get the current saved stack pointer (saved by the compiler on the function prefix).
    __asm { mov ppCurrent, ebp };

    // Don't limit if nLevels is not positive
    if (nLevels <= 0)
        nLevels = 1000000;

    // ebp points to the old call stack, where the first two items look like this:
    // ebp -> [0] Previous ebp
    //        [1] previous program counter
    CallStackItem* pResult = new CallStackItem;
    CallStackItem* pCurItem = pResult;
    int nCurLevel = 0;

    // We need to read two pointers from the stack
    int nRequiredMemorySize = sizeof(void*) * 2;
    while (nCurLevel < nLevels && ppCurrent && !IsBadReadPtr(ppCurrent, nRequiredMemorySize))
    {
        // Keep the previous program counter (where the function will return to)
        pCurItem->pc = ppCurrent[1];
        pCurItem->next = new CallStackItem;

        // Go the the previously kept ebp
        ppCurrent = (void**)*ppCurrent;
        pCurItem = pCurItem->next;
        ++nCurLevel;
    }

    return pResult;
}

void PrintCallStack(CallStackHandle hCallStack)
{
    CallStackItem* pCurItem = (CallStackItem*)hCallStack;
    printf("----- Call stack start -----\n");
    while (pCurItem)
    {
        printf("0x%08x\n", pCurItem->pc);
        pCurItem = pCurItem->next;
    }
    printf("-----  Call stack end  -----\n");
}

void ReleaseCallStack(CallStackHandle hCallStack)
{
    CallStackItem* pCurItem = (CallStackItem*)hCallStack;
    CallStackItem* pPrevItem;
    while (pCurItem)
    {
        pPrevItem = pCurItem;
        pCurItem = pCurItem->next;
        delete pPrevItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use Jochen Kalmbachs [StackWalker](https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker).

I `speedet it up` this way:

- The most time is lost in looking for the `PDB files` in the default directories and PDB Servers.
- I use only `one PDB path` and implemented a `white list` for the images I want to get resolved (no need for me to look for user32.pdb)
- Sometimes I dont need to dive to the bottom, so I defined a `max deep`

code changes:

```
BOOL StackWalker::LoadModules()
{

    ...

    // comment this line out and replace to your pdb path
    // BOOL bRet = this->m_sw->Init(szSymPath);
    BOOL bRet = this->m_sw->Init(<my pdb path>);

    ...

}

BOOL StackWalker::ShowCallstack(int iMaxDeep /* new parameter */ ... )
{

    ... 

// define a maximal deep
// for (frameNum = 0; ; ++frameNum )
    for (frameNum = 0; frameNum < iMaxDeep; ++frameNum )
    {

        ... 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204633%28VS.85%29.aspx - this is "CaptureStackBackTrace", although it's called as "RtlCaptureStackBackTrace".